# Dropdown Picture Menu

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I could create a collapsable dropdown menu showing picture links for my website. Perhaps just simply displaying a dropdown symbol which both opens and collapses to show the site's navigation.

Hoping this is possible?

Comment: I would recommend using a framework/library like Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com)

Answer (score 0):

Add a button or image to the document that will serve as the main
    list activation button.

Create a div element that contains a ul
    element.

In the ul, create li elements that contain the images you
    wish to use.

Wrap each image in an a element (to make them
    clickable).

Use JQuery's slideToggle() method on the click event of
    your button to show/hide the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery, set your links div as hidden then use jquery toggle() or slideToggle() to toggle the hidden div. Here is a fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/edencorbin/x4sw2b6e/2/

HTML

```
    <a href="#" id="dropdownlink"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></a>
    <div class="thediv" hidden="hidden">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></a>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#dropdownlink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.thediv').slideToggle();
      });
    });
```